# Rotation of colorbar tick labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colorbar

I would like to rotate the colorbar tick labels so that they read vertically rather than horizontally. I have tried as many variations as I can think of with `cbar.ax.set_xticklabels` and `cbar.ax.ticklabel_format` and so on with `rotation='vertical'` but haven't quite landed it yet.

I've provided a MWE below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#example function
x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-10,10,200),np.linspace(-10,10,200))
z = x*y*np.exp(-(x+y)**2)

#array for contourf levels
clevs = np.linspace(z.min(),z.max(),50)

#array for colorbar tick labels
clevs1 =np.arange(-200,100,10)

cs1 = plt.contourf(x,y,z,clevs)

cbar = plt.colorbar(cs1, orientation="horizontal")
cbar.set_ticks(clevs1[::1])

plt.show()
```

[image: Example Image]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated - I'm sure this must be pretty simple...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `cbar.ax.set_xticklabels` to change the rotation (or `set_yicklabels` if you had a vertical colorbar).

```
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(clevs1[::1],rotation=90)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

To set the ticks correctly, you can search for where in your `clevs1` array the first tick should be using `np.argmin`, and use that to index `clevs1` when you `set_xticklabels`:

```
tick_start = np.argmin(abs(clevs1-clevs[0]))
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(clevs1[tick_start:],rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: I had looked at this, but it makes the tick labels incorrect.

Comment: what should they be? you have `clevs1`, which goes from -200 to 90, but your example goes from -100 to 0?

Comment: and should the tick labels be different to the actual contour levels? It might be better to use `vmin` and `vmax` for contourf to control the range shown on the colorbar

Comment: The correct values are -100 to 0; `clevs1` is (assuming we don't know the range of data plotted) a list of acceptable values to use as tick labels.

Comment: @KieranHunt OK, so its just a matter of finding the first value in `clevs1` that corresponds to the lowest value of `clevs`. See my edit on how to do that.

Answer (score 13):

This is the idiomatic way to rotate tick labels as of Matplotlib 3.4 (and very likely earlier versions too)

```py
cbar.ax.tick_params(rotation=45)
```

Comment: This is way better than the accepted answer. It is easy to imagine a situation in which the contour levels are not easily accessible, but the `cbar` object is. Besides, I shouldn't _need_ to know the tick positions to rotate the labels.

Answer (score 9):

If you're happy with tick locations and labels and only want to rotate them:

```
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(cbar.ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation='vertical')
```