# what is my colorbar range in python? how do I get the handle?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have been searching, but all I have found is how to set the colorbar range.  How do I actually return what the range is that python is setting by default?  I want to rotate my colorbar labels, but I am fine with the default range python sets to my colorbar, I just do not understand how to get that handle or range it is assigning.

```
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(rotation=70)
```

gives:

```
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(rotation=70)
TypeError: set_xticklabels() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'
```

From the answer to this question, [Rotation of colorbar tick labels in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050030/rotation-of-colorbar-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)  , I know I need to add the range, but I cannot figure out how to do that besides manually putting in a range.

Is there a way to return the range python automatically has placed on my colorbar? Some sort of handle?

Comment: Is the range of the colorbar the same as the range of the data that *created* it?

Comment: yes.. I guess this seems like a stupid question but I really can't get it to work.. i've tried to make the labels=range_data , but it produces just a repeat of a random value, and I cannot figure out where that comes from.  What I have added is : vmin=np.nanmin(data)
vmax=np.nanmax(data)
range_data=np.arange(vmin,vmax)
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(labels=range_data,rotation=70).  The range_data min and max value do not match at all what is shown on the colorbar

Comment: I think you simply didn't read the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38504070/4124317) to the linked question, which says `cbar.ax.set_xticklabels(cbar.ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation='vertical')` and hence does not require you to know the ticklabels at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `values` property should contain the data.

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[1,2,4,7,15,18,30]])
plt.plot(data)
z = plt.contourf(data)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
#pprint(dir(cbar))
print(cbar.values, cbar.vmax, cbar.vmin)
plt.show()
plt.close()


>>> 
(array([  2.,   6.,  10.,  14.,  18.,  22.,  26.,  30.]), 32.0, 0.0)
>>>
```

The `boundaries` property may also be useful

```
>>> cbar.boundaries
array([  0.,   4.,   8.,  12.,  16.,  20.,  24.,  28.,  32.])
>>>
```