# How to rotate custom xtick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following line which I use to add labels to my custom cbar but I don't know how to rotate these label

```
MyCustomBar.set_ticklabels(['< 50 \nand \ndecreasing', '< 50 \nand increasing \nor unchanged', '> 50 \nand decreasing  \nor unchanged', '> 50 \nand \nincreasing'])
```

I tried using  `,rotation = 45` but seems not exist for `set_ticklabels`

Comment: Hi, what library are using for plotting?

Comment: @Laurent Matplotlib

Comment: @TourEiffel Added a tag for you

Comment: Do you mean `MyCustomBar.set_yticklabels(...` (or `MyCustomBar.set_xticklabels(...` for a horizontal colorbar)? `rotation` is handed down to the text, so it is unclear why it would not be recognized. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050030/rotation-of-colorbar-tick-labels-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Toy dataframe
df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()[0:4]

plt.plot(df.index, df["A"], "o--", df.index, df["B"], "x-")
plt.xticks(
    df.index,
    [
        "< 50 \nand \ndecreasing",
        "< 50 \nand increasing \nor unchanged",
        "> 50 \nand decreasing  \nor unchanged",
        "> 50 \nand \nincreasing",
    ],
    rotation=45,
)
```

```py
plt.show()
```

[image]